# How to get localized CMS Element config data in controller of shopware6

Tags: shopware

I have the following situation. I have a custom CMS-Element with a form in it, I send the data via a AJAX in a written JS-Plugin to a custom controller. Now I would like to read informations from the CMS-Element Config. I peeked inside the Source of the Contact-Form and ended in their controller where they read out the configuration. I implemented it in my controller and basicly it worked but the only thing that isn’t working is that I always get the config of one Language (German).
My Primary language is English and my secondary is German.

I took the “Dailymotion” example from the guides. And added melted it with the code from the other guide for AJAX calls. (For testing purpose)

https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/content/cms/add-cms-element
https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/storefront/add-dynamic-content-via-ajax-calls

In the source of the ContactForm (ContactFormRoute.php) are the lines with

```php
$mailConfigs['receivers'] = $slot->getEntities()->first()->getTranslated()['config']['mailReceiver']['value'];
```

https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/d6c853ca3b6b167d61d70e6329f4fcface5c5245/src/Core/Content/ContactForm/SalesChannel/ContactFormRoute.php#L182

I’ve added the same but I only get the secondary language config data.
I modified the code that he get the `dailyUrl` value from the config.

What I noticed is that in my $context the `languageIdChain` contains both language IDs (the first one is the German one) in the contact thereis only the `languageId` of the current language:

These are the `languageIdChain` of the Context sended in the English language. (`2fbb5fe2e29a4d70aa5854ce7ce3e20b` is the English Language)

Context languageIdChain of the Contact form controller:

```php
  #languageIdChain: array:1 [
    0 => "2fbb5fe2e29a4d70aa5854ce7ce3e20b"
  ]
```

Context languageIdChain of my controller:

```php
  #languageIdChain: array:2 [
    0 => "2d7d7d698f634a04b5796e49aa846ae6"
    1 => "2fbb5fe2e29a4d70aa5854ce7ce3e20b"
  ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, you know the moments where you struggle many hours, try this and that and then do the Stack Overflow post an after a half hour you find the solution yourself.

The reason why I always get the German data instead the data of the current Language is that my AJAX call simply calls always the route for the German language `/example` like in the Guide shown.
Instead using a hard coded URL in the JS-Plugin I updated the template

```html
<button id="ajax-button" data-url="{{path('frontend.example.example.submit')}}">Button</button>
```

And in my JS-Plugin I just read out the `data-url`

```js
this.button = this.el.children['ajax-button'];
this.actionUrl = this.button.dataset.url;
```

This ways I get the url `/example` or `/en/example` depending on the current language.